# MySQL Very Large INT fields

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating a table with two columns. [User ID, Number of Points]

Number of Points has a max value of ~100 billion.

Would there be an issue storing Number of Points as an INT value? Or would it need to be a VARCHAR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [BIGINT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html), it will easily hold your range of values.

The maximum value unsigned is (2 ^ 64) - 1, or: 18,446,744,073,709,551,615.

Answer (score 0):

you may try to use `BigInt`, if your version of MySQL is 5.0 or bigger.

Credits from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html)

Answer (score 0):

Info [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html). It is always better to look at the documentation first of whatever the language you are using.

Comment: An answer that simply provides a link is not a good StackOverflow answer.  You should summarize the key points in the link you provide.

Answer (score 0):

See mysql type sizes: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html
100 billion = 10^11 so the type BIGINT will work.